# Waved Curved Tabbar Design in swift 4.2 İOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Wave curved (upside) tabbar behind the center raised button. İ have created a customised class for tabbar by using reference of "https://medium.com/@philipp307/draw-a-custom-ios-tabbar-shape-27d298a7f4fa" But actually İ need to create a Wave Curved in the center of tab bar. İ have tried to play around with Bézier curve but not getting an exact behind the central button. I don't need a dip of it. İ need it behind (upside wave) my custom code and images attached.

```
func createPath() -> CGPath {

    let height: CGFloat = 37.0
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - height * 2), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough

    // first curve down
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 30), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 35, y: height))
    // second curve up
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + height * 2), y: 0),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 35, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 30), y: 0))

    // complete the rect
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
    path.close()
    return path.cgPath
}
```

[tabbar design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMwI7.png)

Comment: why are you curving down first? 
you should curve up and than curve down if you want an upside wave.

Comment: @ValNolav İ need to know the CGPoint.

Comment: what do u mean by knowing CGPoint?

Comment: @ValNolav    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 30), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 35, y: height))
    // second curve up
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + height * 2), y: 0),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 35, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 30), y: 0))

Comment: @ValNolav have you seen my attached image actually İ need to set it like this.

Comment: Yes, I did see your attached desired output which is upcurved. In order to get that, you need to addCurve first going up and down. And on top of that you can add a UIButton.

Comment: @ValNolav Yes İ have tried but not getting an accurate one. let me share my project link. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1evDPYdG2fGiMohWohJR2BQJNsKJHStQy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Newbie were you able to achieve it? can you please share the code